# Weird bug on powerpoint vba

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a "mynote" textbox on a slide. If I execute:

```
Sub test()

            If ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("mynote").Visible Then
                MsgBox "ok"
            End If
end sub
```

It works.

But If I attach a shape with this macro:

```
Sub test(oShape As Shape)

            If ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("mynote").Visible Then
                MsgBox "ok"
            End If
end sub
```

It doesn't work (no error message, no "ok" message)

Comment: Well maybe it works for you, but on my ppt it doesn't trigger the event.

Comment: Well sorry no :) I just want to show a note when clicking on a picture, I'm surprised I can't do it!

Comment: How are you executing this method? Does this trigger through a click event somewhere? Have you tried setting a break point, to see if the second method gets executed?

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on how you call it from another sub routine - you have to send in a shape. Like:

```
Sub testYourTest()
    Dim sh As Shape
    Set sh = ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes(1)
    test sh
End Sub
```

You can't run `test` stand-alone because it is expecting you to send in a `Shape` object. But seeing as your `oShape` object is not being used in your `test` routine, you may as well remove it.

Comment: I call it when clicking on a picture so it sends a shape but still it doesn't work.